# Google Maps Api Integration in Win32 C/C++ Desktop Application

Tags: c, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, desktop-application

We want to integrate Google maps into our C/C++ win32 application.
The whole idea is when user runs the application for the first time we request them to mark their location and then retrieve the coordinates of the user selected location and save into a database or file.

After it has been initialized we want to provide user with some pre tagged places and allow user to find direction from their place to that place. The coordinates of the pre tagged locations will be provided.

Is it possible to achieve what we want by using Google Api's, if yes then how??
And if there are legal issues regarding it??

Thanks.

Comment: Commercial app? In that case you'll probably need a commercial agreement.

Comment: Have you tried Gmap.Net?

Answer (score 1):

For the answer to the legal question, the best place is to look at the Terms of Service, and then to consult a lawyer of course. Both terms of service for the Maps API as well as the Maps for Business Terms of Service explicitly prohibit the usage of geocoding data if it is not in conjunction with a Google Map:

Maps API TOS, relevant point is Section 10.1.1 (g):
https://developers.google.com/maps/terms#section_10_1

Business Maps Purchase Agreement, relevant point is 4.1 (l):
https://www.google.com/enterprise/earthmaps/legal/us/maps_purchase_agreement.html

If you need a more liberal alternative you might want to look at http://www.openstreetmap.org/ - the geocoding data offered there is covered under the Open Database License, which permits usage with attribution.

http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Legal_FAQ

Answer (score 0):

You can use Qt framework on Windows. You can integrate your win32 application with Qt. In Qt you may use **QWebKit** framework to communicate with your app and a webpage(which, in this scenario is a page containing a map from Google Maps) . Actually you can write hybrid applications with Qt. Take a look at Qt **QWebKit** documentation.

Comment: is it legal to store the information(latitude and longitude) retrieved from google api's into local database.
and is there any inbuilt function in QT to retrieve the latitude and longitude information of the place selected by user and provide pre tagged location into the map....

Comment: I think there is no problem. Google maps apis work with javascript. So first of all you should retrieve the lng/lat using JavaScript and then bring it to your app using Qt WebKit .

Comment: Qt is not Win32 API, so the answer doesn't relate to the question

Comment: @MichaelHaephrati I didn't say Qt is Win32 API, Read my answer again. I said you can integrate you Win32 Application with Qt. Read the answer and then downvote. Maybe you have just had the ability to downvote. Test it in a proper place.

Comment: I want to upvote your answer but can't because you need to change it first. You did indicate that the Win API application can be integrated with Qt but again, that doesn't solve the problem. Not everyone wish to use Qt and the question is about using pure Win32 API without adding or integrating to anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I needed the same and solved it by interfacing Google Maps via a Browser object.

*** Please read about [WebBrowser control compatibility](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/patricka/2015/01/12/controlling-webbrowser-control-compatibility/) and follow the instructions.

1. Create an [MFC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9es9d1k4.aspx) dialog based project.
2. Add a CExplorer control. (See: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752046(v=vs.85).aspx).
3. When the main dialog of your program initializes, you need to initialize a global object

   ```
    CExplorer1 m_Browser;
   ```
4. The first building block would be WriteHTML()

   ```
   void WriteHTML(const wchar_t* html)

   {

      IDispatch* pHtmlDoc = m_Browser.get_Document();

      if (!pHtmlDoc)

          return;

      CComPtr<IHTMLDocument2> doc1 = NULL;

      doc1.Detach();

      doc1.Attach((IHTMLDocument2*)pHtmlDoc);

      if (!doc1)

          return;

      // Creates a new one-dimensional array

      SAFEARRAY* psaStrings = SafeArrayCreateVector(VT_VARIANT, 0, 1);

      if (!psaStrings)

          return;

      BSTR bstr = SysAllocString(html);

      if (bstr)

      {

          VARIANT* param;

          HRESULT hr = SafeArrayAccessData(psaStrings, (LPVOID*)&param);

          if (SUCCEEDED(hr))

          {

              param->vt = VT_BSTR;

              param->bstrVal = bstr;

              hr = SafeArrayUnaccessData(psaStrings);

              if (SUCCEEDED(hr))

              {

                  doc1->write(psaStrings);

                  doc1->close();

              }

          }

      }

      // SafeArrayDestroy calls SysFreeString for each BSTR!

      if (psaStrings)

          SafeArrayDestroy(psaStrings);
    }
   ```
5. You should also add the browser control to your .rs file

   **CONTROL         "",IDC_SGWEBBROWSER,"{8856F961-340A-11D0-A96B-
                  00C04FD705A2}",WS_TABSTOP,388,36,236,281**
6. Among several ways to implement it, I found that creating a temporary HTML based on the coordinates and calling: `m_Browser.Navigate(FileName, 0, 0, 0, 0);` 
   is the best.
7. "FileName" is created based on the requested coordinates of the point on the map, along with other attributes as follow:
8. Assign a name and path to "FileName":

   ```
     wchar_t FileName[2048];

     GetCurrentDirectory(2048, FileName);

     wcscat(FileName, L"\\test.html");
   ```
9. Filling the file with data and opening it with the browser control, whilst navigating Google Maps to the requested location:

Variables:

a. **Latitude**

b. **Longitude**

c. **zoom** (set to 10)

d. **API key**. (you need to [obtain one](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/get-api-key))

Code (an alternative to the **WriteHTML** function)

```
CString HTML_TEXT;
CRect rect;
CWnd *pWnd = GetDlgItem(IDC_SGWEBBROWSER);
pWnd->GetWindowRect(&rect);
int w = rect.Width()-50, h = rect.Height()-50;
HTML_TEXT.Format(L"<!DOCTYPE html><html><meta http-equiv=\"X - UA - Compatible\" content=\"IE = edge\"><body><div id =\"googleMap\" style=\"width:%dpx;height:%dpx\"><script>function myMap(){var mapProp = {center:new google.maps.LatLng(%f, %f), zoom : 10};var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(\"googleMap\"), mapProp);marker = new google.maps.Marker({position: new google.maps.LatLng(%f, %f),map: map});}</script><script src = \"https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=%s&callback=myMap\"></script></div></body></html>", w, h, Latitude, Longitude, Latitude, Longitude, API_KEY);
FILE *fp = _wfopen(FileName, L"w");
fwprintf(fp, L"%s", HTML_TEXT.GetBuffer());
fclose(fp);
m_Browser.Navigate(FileName, 0, 0, 0, 0);
```